# properties of a and b in G group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

let $a$ and $b$ two elements of a group $G$.

1.show that: $(ab)^{-1} =b^{-1} a^{-1}$.

2-prove that: $ab=ba$ if and only if $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1} b^{-1}$.

I try to prove that the following way
$(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1} b^{-1} =b^{-1} a^{-1}$

Comment: Which one of the statements are you trying to prove that way?

Comment: To show 1, by definition $(ab)^{-1}$ is the unique element $x\in G$ such that $xab=1_G=abx$.

Comment: I tried to prove the second statement

Comment: I edited my answer to give more details. Is it now clear? You can ask if you don't understand something.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Your proof assumes that $xy=yx$. Is that true?

If $x$ and $y$ are each others inverses, then $xy=1=yx$. Thus, if $ab$ and $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ are each others inverses, then ...

(2) Inverses are unique, look at the inverses of $ab$ and $ba$ with (1) in mind.

So much for hints, now more explicit:

(1) Compute $(ab)(ab)^{-1}=(ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1})=a(bb^{-1})a^{-1}=aa^{-1}=1$. Thus this must indeed be the (unique) inverse of $ab$.

(2) If $ab=ba$ then $(ab)^{-1}=(ba)^{-1}$, thus $(ab)^{-1}=(ba)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ because of (1).

The other way: We could be done by saying inverses are unique, and since the inverse of $ab$ is the same as the inverse for $ba$, it must be that $ab=ba$. More explicit: We have $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ but we still have the result in (1): $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ and $(ba)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$. Combining this gives $b^{-1}a^{-1}=(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}=(ba)^{-1}$.